# I got the following error when I run cucumber test in a gradle tasks. my ruby version is: 2.2 and cucumber version is 1.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

`Argument to bundle: [exec, cucumber, -p, default, ~@mask1, --format, junit, --out, STDOUT]`

`Successfully started process 'command 'bundle''`

`All but one formatter must use --out, only one can print to each stream (or STDOUT) (RuntimeError)`

the Gemfiles:

```
gem 'rake', '~>0.9.6', :require => false
gem 'rspec', '~> 2.0.0'
gem "capybara", "~> 1.1.2"
gem "selenium-webdriver", "~> 2.41.0"
gem 'cucumber', '~>1.2.5'
```

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/pull/434

one --format must one --out.